# Binary reversed to decimal number

Tags: c++

> Create a template function named reversed_binary_value. It must take an arbitrary number of bool values as template parameters. These booleans represent binary digits in reverse order. Your function must return an integer corresponding to the binary value of the digits represented by the booleans. For example: reversed_binary_value<0,0,1>() should return.

This is the problem and I solved in that way.

```
template<bool...digits>
int reversed_binary_value()
{
    vector<bool> vec = {digits...};
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        result += pow(2 * vec[i],  i);        
    return result;
}

template <int N>
void sum()
{
    std::cout << "Number is: ";
}

int main()
{
     std::cout << reversed_binary_value<1,0,0,0,1,1>();
    //sum<reversed_binary_value<1,0,0,0,1,1>()>();
}
```

I'm trying to call function sum but i got this error: call to non-constexpr function 'int reversed_binary_value(). 
I know for is not compile time instruction. My question is, how can i call function sum ?

Comment: Why `sum` has to take its argument through a `template` value? This is impossible with your current approach, since it would require `reversed_binary_value` to be able to be evaluated at compile time, but creation of an `std::vector` makes it impossible as of current standard.

Comment: You left out the end of the problem statement.

Comment: I know is it impossible to do in that way. I wanna know how can i implement function `int reversed_binary_value()` to be possible.

Comment: But.. that's literally the assignment. You're supposed to think about it and work it out  Not just get us to give you the solution...

Comment: Make it `constexpr` and don't use any heap allocation, since that's not allowed as of right now in `constexpr` context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename = void>
constexpr int binary() {
        return 0;
}
template <bool d, bool...digits>
constexpr int binary() {
        return d + 2 * binary<digits...>();
}

template <int N>
void sum() {
        std::cout << N;
}
int main() {
        sum<binary<1,0,1>()>(); // prints 5
}
```

This allows you to add `constexpr` for the binary function (no loops), and allows the constant propagation required for the template call to sum :)

Answer (score 0):

The result of `reversed_binary_value()` cannot be used as a template argument since it is not determined at compile-time (to be that it would need to be a `constexpr`, but it cannot be that with the current definition). Instead of defining `sum()` as a template function, you can just make it a regular function taking the integer as argument:

```
void sum(int N)
{
    std::cout << "Number is: " << N;
}

int main()
{
     std::cout << reversed_binary_value<1,0,0,0,1,1>() << std::endl;
     sum(reversed_binary_value<1,0,0,0,1,1>());
}
```

One additional thing: instead of depending on the `pow()` function to calculate the power of 2, you can use bit-shift as follows:

```
    result += vec[i] * (1u << i);
```